# Unity notifications from BBC News do not disappear when I click them

Tags: firefox, webapps

I have a problem with Firefox Unity integration on the BBC News website.  The headline notifications never disappear until I click them.  Most other programs' notifications disappear after a while.

Preferably I'd like them to time out on their own, but I've also tried removing them entirely, by deleting `~/.local/share/applications/BBCNewsbbccouk.desktop`, however this file reappears the next time I go back to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will admit I am unsure how to make the notifications go away but if you want to uninstall the Webapp do as follows

1. Download **Synaptic Package Manager** either from the USC or by executing the command `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
2. In the synaptic search bar look up *unity-webapps-bbcnews*
3. Click the green square and select **remove**

Alternatively if you prefer not to use the GUI you can just type into the terminal `sudo apt-get purge unity-webapps-bbcnews` and disregard all previous steps

Comment: Thanks, I can live without the integrated notifications.  Hadn't realised that when you get the prompt inside Firefox to install the integration, that it actually installed a package rather than merely activating something that was already installed.

Comment: Glad to help kind sir